# Is it possible to copy keyframes infinitely across a specific frame rate?

Tags: animation, rigging, edit-mode, keyframes, pose-mode

So I made a copy of my animation to another character and now i have to go in every 5 frames to change a specific position.

Is there an easier way to just copy this specific frame across my entire animation aka every 5 frames instead of manually going through each 1000s of frames?

I want to copy my frame 55 movement across each 5 frames after, so replace 60, 65, 70 etc.

However, the only method I see now is to manually drag them over each frame even which seems very tedious for something that could be spread across my frame with a simple input of saying to display every 5 frames after my current frame of 55

[image]

Comment: Add Cycles modifier to this specific F-Curve under Graph Editor's side panel (N)? If this doesn't solve your needs, specify closer the kind of your animation. Thanks

Comment: python would be another way...but of course this needs some coding skills